# PyQt, expanding editor in QTableView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm working on a project that uses PyQt and I have a problem with QTableView and its item editor. My TableModel has 2 columns with data which are tightly coupled and have to change simultaneously.
I've reimplemented QStyledItemDelegate class with QComboBox inherited editor. All this works perfectly.
But I need my editor open on two columns. All examples I've found open the editor only on one cell where the user clicks. Examples use reimplemented updateEditorGeometry method to update geometry on the base of option argument. Is it possible to get width of neighbour column in updateEditorGeometry method to count total width of two cols and update editor (combobox) geometry on its base?

My current (minimal) QStyledItemDelegate based class:

```
class ComboBoxDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):

  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(SpinBoxDelegate, self).__init__(parent)

  def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
    editor = QComboBox(parent)
    return editor

  def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
    pass


  def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
    pass


  def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
    row = index.row()
    column = index.column()
    if column == 1:
        neighbourIndex = index.model().index(row, 0, QModelIndex())
    editor.setGeometry(option.rect)
```

Comment: How "tightly" is the data coupled? Should the combos react to each other? Can you please clarify the relationship between the combos and with the model?

Comment: They are "code" and "name" fields from SQL table. They are always change simultaneously. I mean that I have problem to show combobox which occupy visually two columns of table. There is no problem to deal with model data

Comment: @BVZ Create a second [QStyleOptionViewItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleoptionviewitem.html) and then [initialise it](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#initStyleOption) from the neighbour index.

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes, I tried this way but new QStyleOptionViewItem from neighbour index return empty QRect with QStyleOption.rect() method

Comment: @BVZ In that case, you can use `self.parent().visualRect(neighbourIndex)` (assuming you set the table-view as the parent of the delegate).

Answer (score 0):

@ekhumoro comment is key!
Here updateEditorGeometry() code snippet

```
        def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
          row = index.row()
          column = index.column()
          if column == 1:
            neighbourIndex = index.model().index(row, 0, QModelIndex())
          neighbourRect = self.parent().visualRect(neighbourIndex)
          width = option.rect.width() + neighbourRect.width()
          newRect = QRect(option.rect)
          newRect.setWidth(width)
          newRect.moveLeft(0)
          editor.setGeometry(newRect)
```

View must be a parent of delegate